# What are some Career options after QA Testing field?

Tags: agile, team-management, scrum, career-development, tester

I am a Lead QA/Testing Engineer on the team who has worked on lot of Good manual/black-box testing and Automation testing projects, throughout my career. Now I'm a bit confused and Not sure what will be next in my Career path or progression.

At the best I can become a QA Manager or a Director in many years or I can take role of a Scrum master/Agile coach as im planning to take a Scrum certification.

Could you please throw some light on some Career path that Senior/Lead QA can take?

Comment: Title means nothing in a IT world you can be director of engnieer and still be doing infrastructure engineer job .  You can be a Team lead and still be just a team player . Its about what you want and enjoy doing at the end of the day ,

Comment: QA Manager, Project Manager, Developer, SDET, etc.

Answer (score 5):

> Could you please throw some light on some Career path that Senior/Lead QA can take?

The answer to this can be quite personal as it's based on what you like doing and your own personality.

- Do you like doing the testing work and engineering?
- People management?
- Creating strategy?

Answering these questions can help narrow down your path.

If you like testing and QA Engineering:

- Principal QA Engineer
- QA Architect
- Principal SDET
- QA Manager

If you want to stay in engineering but branch out:

- Software Developer/Web App Developer
- DevOps Engineer
- UX Engineer

If you want to do more people management:

- QA Manager
- Director level

If you want to do more project level management:

- Scrum coach
- Project Manager
- Product Manager

Like mentioned in a comment, there tends to be less meaning on job titles in tech. And not every job title will exist in every company. It's possible these general titles go by different names in other companies.

Other things to keep in mind.

- Maybe try work in a different industry than you've worked in before. Example, if you've never done ecommerce work, find a role with an ecommerce company. Lots of industries need tech workers.
- Maybe work at a startup if you haven't done so yet. There will be new challenges to encounter.
- Maybe work at a big tech company if you haven't done so.

> experienced in good manual/black-box testing

Branch out your skillset and learn white-box testing, become an SDET and learn more automation skills. Have you ever created an automation solution from scratch before? This is a different skillset than just being a contributor to what someone else has built. Have you always done web software work? Try mobile app testing. Always done mobile testing? Try web application testing. Also, see a similar question [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/49192/can-a-test-automation-engineer-switch-to-a-devops-profile-easily/49193#49193).

*There's a lot more to testing and QA work then just doing "manual/black-box testing."*

Just keep asking yourself questions about what you like to do, what you're interested in doing, and discovering other areas of tech you haven't tried yet. *Follow people online in QA or other areas of interest. You can learn a ton by following people on social media and blog sites.*

Since the OP is doing a Scrum certification, that's likely your next path.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very exciting question. I myself have been working as a test engineer, test management, and in consulting for 23 years now.

But I have specialized myself. I started in the games industry here as a tester for larger games projects. Then I switched to Siemens and more classic projects.

I think, to get to the point, that everyone has to go his own way, also in the area of testing. I think you should look for the path that suits you best.

I myself have been developing in the field of test engineering for the last 15 years:

- Security Testing
- Testing on cloud based solutions
- AWS security
- Magento projects
- Scrum/Agile and Scrum in large projects
- AWS and DevOp skills
- Various development languages

But the question is what do they want?

I myself have decided for myself not to be a full QA manager. That is simply too boring for me.